# Multi thread to show java console log in GUI JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I got a little problem with Multi-thread

I created a java class `InformationConsole` to get my java console log, everytime when I use `System.out.print("...");` The message will send to a JTextArea, it works like a "connection" with java console and my JTextArea

```
public class InformationConsole extends OutputStream  {
   private JTextArea textArea;
   private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   private String title;

   public InformationConsole(final JTextArea textArea, String title) {
      this.textArea = textArea;
      this.title = title;
      sb.append(title + "> ");
   }

   @Override
   public void flush() {
   }

   @Override
   public void close() {
   }

   @Override
   public void write(int b) throws IOException {

      if (b == '\r')
         return;

      if (b == '\n') {
         final String text = sb.toString() + "\n";
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               textArea.append(text);
            }
         });
         sb.setLength(0);
         sb.append(title + "> ");
         return;
      }
      sb.append((char) b);
   }
}
```

And I use it with my GUI to show the log

```
public class Lancer{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             CreerEtAffichierGUI();
         }
      });
    }

   public static void CreerEtAffichierGUI(){
    JFrame fenetre = new JFrame();
    JTextArea log = new JTextArea();
    InformationConsole consoleInfo = new InformationConsole(log, "InfoConsole");

    fenetre.setVisible(true);
    fenetre.setResizable(false);
    fenetre.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    fenetre.setTitle("Modélisation" );
    fenetre.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 800);
    fenetre.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton bouton1 = new JButton("Start" );
    fenetre.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
     //On ajoute le bouton au content pane de la JFrame
    fenetre.getContentPane().add(bouton1); 
    fenetre.getContentPane(). add(new JScrollPane(log, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER));System.setOut(new PrintStream(consoleInfo));
    bouton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CreerModelJCL();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fenetre, "Modelisation JCL Fini");
        }
    });
    fenetre.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

The JTextArea which in GUI don't update in real time, it will show all the log when the application finish, I am a newbee with multi thread, I couldn't find out why...

Could u please give me some help ?

Here is `CreerModelJCL()` He just have a lot of `println` with the console

```
public static void CreerModelJCL(){

System.out.println("--------  Exporter fichier résultat XMI Fini--------------");

System.out.println("------------------------Modelisation JCL    FINI------------------------");

}
```

Comment: Please add the code for `CreerModelJCL();` I tested your program by replacing this method call with a loop running in a new Thread that prints some text to the console every second and it works fine. So I suspect that that method (which I assume produces some output in the console) is running on the GUI thread, and locking the GUI from any updates.

Comment: @d.j.brown added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the method `CreerModelJCL()` on a new thread and not the event dispatch (GUI) thread. Effectively you are locking the event dispatch thread until the operation conducted by `CreetModelJCL()` is completed.

For example:

```
bouton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 CreerModelJCL();
            }
        }).start();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fenetre, "Modelisation JCL Fini");
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you every much ;)